# Within Karate UI, is it a way to create custom UI keyword

Tags: karate

In my tests, I do often the same actions for some composant.
In order to avoid code repetion, is it a way to factorize using a customKeyword my repetiting code?

for example, to select an item in a list, I do:

```
scroll("#myList")
click("#myList")
click("{}MyItem")
```

Is it a way to create a keyword such as

```
selectCustomList("#myList","MyItem")
```

and the selectCustomList keyword will handle my actions to do the selection.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Use a re-usable function, explained in the docs: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-core#code-reuse

Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76303039/143475 | https://stackoverflow.com/a/63339200/143475